# Number of swap operations in Bubble Sort

Tags: sorting

I was trying to solve this question:

**Given a list of integers with no duplicates, find out how many swaps it will take to sort the list in increasing order using Bubble sort.**

**Input:**
First line of each test case will contain an integer T = number of test cases. Each test case will contain two lines. First line will contain a number N = no. of elements in the list. Next line will contain N space separated numbers. 1 <= N <= 50.

**Output:**
For each test case, print on a single line, number of swaps required to sort the list in increasing order using Bubble sort.

---

Test cases:

```
3
5
2 1 4 6 3
10 
123 21 34 45 25 675 23 44 55 900
1
23
```

Output:
    3
    16
    0

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int testcase,num_elements,i=0,j,n,count=0,flag=0,temp;
    int array[1000000];
    scanf("%d",&testcase);
    while(testcase--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&num_elements);
        n=num_elements;
    while(i<n && scanf("%d",&array[i])==1)
    i++;
        for(j=1;j<=n-1;j++)
        {
            flag=0;
            for(i=0;i<=n-j-1;i++)
                {
                    if(array[i]>array[i+1])
                    {
                        temp=array[i];
                        array[i]=array[i+1];
                        array[i+1]=temp;
                        flag=1;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            break;
        }

        }
            printf("%d\n",count);
    }
 return 0;
}
```

It gives correct output in first and last test case but not in second one.

Please point out the mistake.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Question was obscured at the bottom by formatting, but alas, the question seems still to be of the "why is my homework not working?" variety.  Please edit to present evidence that the code does not work, and provide your own theory as to why not.

Comment: Please do not write the title of your question with all caps. If you read only a couple of questions here before posting yours you would notice it is not customary.

Comment: What is the output you're expecting? What is the incorrect output you are getting, and what were you expecting instead?

Answer (score 2):

Re-initialise count  to 0 inside the while loop. In your code the value of count is getting carried over to all the test cases.

Also initialise `i=0` inside the while loop before you begin getting the input numbers.

Comment: Probably right.  I don't think the question merited your good effort, but +1 nevertheless.